# How do I use a local folder as collection instead of an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rekognition

I'm trying to compare a single human face picture to a collection of group photos in a specific folder.

I'm trying to eliminate the use of S3 buckets and would like to use local folders

```
from pprint import pprint
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rekognition')

with open('./faces/me.jpg', 'rb') as face:
    face_bytes = face.read()


response = client.search_faces_by_image(CollectionId="[EXPECTING LOCAL FOLDER AS RESOURCE]",
                                        FaceMatchThreshold=80,
                                        Image={'Bytes': face_bytes })

pprint(response)
```

When I try to give local folder that contains other images to be searched, the errors I get are: ResourceNotFoundException(obviously) and others related to regular expressions. Please help on how I can pass local folder as a collection to CollectionId argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how Rekognition `search_faces_by_image` works. The `collection` cannot be a folder of images stored locally. Instead, it's a collection of face vectors stored in the Rekognition service. You initially populate the collection by calling [index_faces](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.index_faces) against each image (containing a face) that you want to be in the collection.

If you really don't want to create a collection, then you could call [compare_faces](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.compare_faces), comparing the source image to each target image, one-by-one.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to learn S3 and then start looking into the other boto functions. Looks like there's no other way to use a local directory mechanism. I did try with compare_faces() but let's say if I have a folder containing 1000 images, and if I iterate one face with many pictures in the target folder, compare_faces() executing multiple times is using up the free-tier quota very quickly. Anyways, I'll see what I can head towards.

Comment: S3 is simple to learn and use, but in this case you don’t strictly have to use S3. You can create a face collection by sending each image as a byte buffer. You don’t have to send a reference to an image in S3.